# Spring security SAML Single logout service URL hitting twice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

getting issue while logging out using  the SAML SSL. SingleLogoutService URL hitting twice.

[image]
**SSL configuration in IDP.xml(SP) below:**

```
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
Location="https://sso-example.com/saml/idp/profile/post/sls">  
</SingleLogoutService>
```

**https://sso-example.com/saml/idp/profile/post/sls** (hitting twice)

while hitting first it destroys cookies & response was success and again second time hits the same url and return back error msg in response.

**Spring security configuration in SP:**

```
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>  
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>  
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>  
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>  
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>  
    </security:filter-chain-map>  
</bean>

   <!-- Handler for successful logout -->  
<bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">  
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login/logout.psg"/>  
</bean>  

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->  
<bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->  
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->  
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>
```

would you please tell me  at what scenario this will happens ? and Is there any changes needed to fix ?